# TextBox с иконкой

Tags: winforms

Как отобразить в углу `TextBox` иконку, например, в левом углу "лупу" или в правом - "вопрос", при наведении на который всплывал бы `ToolTip`?

**UPDATE**

Аккумулируя похожие темы ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868817/button-inside-a-winforms-textbox), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201011/windows-form-how-to-add-an-icon-to-the-right-or-left-of-a-text-box)) на англоязычном разделе, вот что получилось:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class TextBoxRightImage : TextBox
    {
        private PictureBox _pictureBox;
        private ToolTip _toolTip;
        private const int EM_SETMARGINS = 0xd3;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

        public TextBoxRightImage()
        {
            _pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            _pictureBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
            _pictureBox.Size = new Size(16, 16);
            _pictureBox.TabIndex = 0;
            _pictureBox.TabStop = false;
            _pictureBox.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            this.Controls.Add(_pictureBox);
            SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETMARGINS, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(16 << 16));
            _toolTip = new ToolTip();
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Description("Иконка")]
        public Image RightImage
        {
            set
            {
                _pictureBox.Image = value;
                _pictureBox.Left = this.Width - _pictureBox.Size.Width - 4;
                _pictureBox.Top = this.Height - _pictureBox.Size.Height - 4;
            }
            get
            {
                return _pictureBox.Image;
            }
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Description("Текст всплывающей подсказки")]
        public string ToolTipText
        {
            set
            {
                this._toolTip.SetToolTip(this._pictureBox, value);
            }
            get
            {
                return this._toolTip.GetToolTip(this._pictureBox);
            }
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Description("Иконка всплывающей подсказки")]
        public ToolTipIcon ToolTipIcon
        {
            set
            {
                this._toolTip.ToolTipIcon = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return this._toolTip.ToolTipIcon;
            }
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Description("Заголовок всплывающей подсказки")]
        public string ToolTipTitle
        {
            set
            {
                this._toolTip.ToolTipTitle = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return this._toolTip.ToolTipTitle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Элементы Windows Forms отрисовываются с помощью GDI. Можете переопределить методы перерисовки контрола.
[MSDN OnPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая тот факт, что вам над картинкой еще и вслывающую подсказку надо показывать, то можно сделать такой трюк:

1. Добавить `Panel`, сделать ее белого цвета.
2. В панель добавить `TextBox` и `PictureBox`. Причем текстбокс должен по высоте совпадать с панелью, у него должен отсутствовать бордер.
3. К `PictureBox` крепите `ToolTip`.

Т.о. вы имитируете текстбокс, у которого внутрь поля для ввода текста встроена картинка (да еще и с подсказкой).

Answer (score 0):

В `WindowsForm`  без проблем можно просто добавить `Image`, по слою вывести его выше `TextBox` и картинку в свойствах добавить, и дополнительно в `TextBox` нужно добавить отступ текста от начала `TextBox` или конца, в зависимости от того, где вы планируете вставить картинку.
Ну и со стандартных эвэнтов уже можете добавить всплывающее сообщение.